# unset all id keys from multidimensional array

Tags: php

How to unset all keys named `id` from a multidimensional array?

```
private function remove_id(Array &$arr){
    foreach($arr as $key => $value){
        if($key == 'id'){
            unset($arr[$key]);
        }
        elseif(is_array($value)){
            $this->remove_id($value);
        }
    }
}
```

## array

```
Array
(
    [id] => 52453
    [periods] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 95296
                    [is_readonly] => 0
                    [year] => 2016
                    [month] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 95297
                    [is_readonly] => 0
                    [year] => 2016
                    [month] => 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 95298
                    [is_readonly] => 0
                    [year] => 2016
                    [month] => 3
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 95299
                    [is_readonly] => 0
                    [year] => 2016
                    [month] => 4
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 95300
                    [is_readonly] => 0
                    [year] => 2016
                    [month] => 5
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 95301
                    [is_readonly] => 0
                    [year] => 2016
                    [month] => 6
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 95302
                    [is_readonly] => 0
                    [year] => 2016
                    [month] => 7
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 95303
                    [is_readonly] => 0
                    [year] => 2016
                    [month] => 8
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 95304
                    [is_readonly] => 0
                    [year] => 2016
                    [month] => 9
                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 95305
                    [is_readonly] => 0
                    [year] => 2016
                    [month] => 10
                )

            [10] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 95306
                    [is_readonly] => 0
                    [year] => 2016
                    [month] => 11
                )

            [11] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 95307
                    [is_readonly] => 0
                    [year] => 2016
                    [month] => 12
                )

        )

    [closing_profit_amount] => 0
    [closing_profit_net_amount] => 0
)
```

Comment: the only wrong thing i can see is that you are modifying the object you are iterating on, which may lead to unexpected side effects. But does this give you any error or it just doesn't work?

Comment: its not returning errors.. but the array is not modified

Comment: can we see the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `&value` in the `for` loop to keep changes in nested arrays.

Also the array cannot have more than 1 `id` key, so there is no need to check it within the loop, which allow a bit of microoptimization here:

```
private function remove_id(Array &$arr){
    if(isset($arr['id'])) {
        unset($arr['id']);
    }
    foreach($arr as &$value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            $this->remove_id($value);
        }
    }
}
```